# Issue with migration from Wagtail 2.7.1 to 2.7.4

Tags: python, django, postgresql, migration, wagtail

I had to upgrade Wagtail along with Django for some security updates. When a blow away my local database and rerun the migrations, I get the following errors. My backend is Postgres.

Django version: 2.2.13
Postrges version: 9.4

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, authtoken, contenttypes, cpe, cve4, cvss2, cvss3, enrichment, sessions, taggit, vulnerability, wagtailadmin, wagtailcore, wagtaildocs, wagtailembeds, wagtailforms, wagtailimages, wagtailredirects, wagtailsearch, wagtailusers
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... OK
  Applying auth.0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length... OK
  Applying authtoken.0001_initial... OK
  Applying authtoken.0002_auto_20160226_1747... OK
  Applying cpe.0001_initial... OK
  Applying cpe.0002_auto_20200129_1941... OK
  Applying cpe.0003_auto_20200330_2229... OK
  Applying cve4.0001_initial... OK
  Applying cvss3.0001_initial... OK
  Applying cvss3.0002_auto_20200130_0403... OK
  Applying cvss2.0001_initial... OK
  Applying cvss2.0002_auto_20200130_0403... OK
  Applying cve4.0002_auto_20200102_2244... OK
  Applying cve4.0003_auto_20200106_1747... OK
  Applying cve4.0004_auto_20200130_0403... OK
  Applying cve4.0005_auto_20200330_2255... OK
  Applying cve4.0006_foxscore... OK
  Applying enrichment.0001_initial... OK
  Applying enrichment.0002_auto_20200205_1925... OK
  Applying enrichment.0003_githubrepository_link... OK
  Applying enrichment.0004_auto_20200205_2220... OK
  Applying enrichment.0005_auto_20200205_2339... OK
  Applying enrichment.0006_enrichmentmetrics... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
  Applying taggit.0001_initial... OK
  Applying taggit.0002_auto_20150616_2121... OK
  Applying taggit.0003_taggeditem_add_unique_index... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0001_squashed_0016_change_page_url_path_to_text_field... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0017_change_edit_page_permission_description... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0018_pagerevision_submitted_for_moderation_index... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0019_verbose_names_cleanup... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0020_add_index_on_page_first_published_at... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0021_capitalizeverbose... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0022_add_site_name... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0023_alter_page_revision_on_delete_behaviour... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0024_collection... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0025_collection_initial_data... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0026_group_collection_permission... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0027_fix_collection_path_collation... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0024_alter_page_content_type_on_delete_behaviour... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0028_merge... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0029_unicode_slugfield_dj19... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0030_index_on_pagerevision_created_at... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0031_add_page_view_restriction_types... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0032_add_bulk_delete_page_permission... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0033_remove_golive_expiry_help_text... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0034_page_live_revision... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0035_page_last_published_at... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0036_populate_page_last_published_at... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0037_set_page_owner_editable... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0038_make_first_published_at_editable... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0039_collectionviewrestriction... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0040_page_draft_title... OK
  Applying wagtailcore.0041_group_collection_permissions_verbose_name_plural... OK
  Applying vulnerability.0001_initial... OK
  Applying vulnerability.0002_vulnerabilitypage... OK
  Applying vulnerability.0003_auto_20200124_1520... OK
  Applying vulnerability.0004_auto_20200124_1857... OK
  Applying vulnerability.0005_vulnerabilitypage_subtitle... OK
  Applying vulnerability.0006_vulnerabilitypage_vulnerable_products... OK
  Applying vulnerability.0007_auto_20200220_1758... OK
  Applying vulnerability.0008_remove_vulnerabilitypage_risk_score... OK
  Applying wagtailadmin.0001_create_admin_access_permissions...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "ON"
LINE 1: ...ions" ("group_id", "permission_id") VALUES (1, 1) ON CONFLIC...
                                                             ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/cve-api/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "/srv/cve-api/manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 245, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/special.py", line 190, in database_forwards
    self.code(from_state.apps, schema_editor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/wagtail/admin/migrations/0001_create_admin_access_permissions.py", line 26, in create_admin_access_permissions
    group.permissions.add(admin_permission)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 952, in add
    through_defaults=through_defaults,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 1136, in _add_items
    ], ignore_conflicts=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 507, in bulk_create
    objs_without_pk, fields, batch_size, ignore_conflicts=ignore_conflicts,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1272, in _batched_insert
    self._insert(item, fields=fields, using=self.db, ignore_conflicts=ignore_conflicts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1249, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1395, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "ON"
LINE 1: ...ions" ("group_id", "permission_id") VALUES (1, 1) ON CONFLIC...
```

The error from the postgres/container side is a bit more complete:

```
db_1         | ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ON" at character 82
db_1         | STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO "auth_group_permissions" ("group_id", "permission_id") VALUES (1, 1) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
```

I can't seem to figure out why this is happening and how I can fix it. As far as I can tell, there shouldn't be any issues since this is a completely fresh install (locally) with no schemas or data in the database when the migration is ran.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: what is the  Django version and Postgres version

Comment: I updated my question, sorry about that. But, django version: 2.2.13
Postgres version: 9.4

Comment: Are you sure about it as it does look like you have updated it to 3.0  for reasons stated in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have mistakenly updated Django to version 3.* as

Django 3.0 [dropped support for PostgreSQL 9.4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/3.0/#dropped-support-for-postgresql-9-4) which is visible in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/databases/#postgresql-notes) too

PosgreSQL 9.5 has new ON CONFLICT Clause in [insert statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-insert.html) which was not available in prior PostgreSQL versions and Django makes use of it

Have in mind that  PostgreSQL 9.4 is no longer supported by PostgreSQL team and should be updated